# Node exec `test -e` command

Tags: node.js, bash

When I'm trying to do smth like below:

```
exec('test -e package.json && npm install', function (err, stdout, stderr) {...});
```

And I'm getting an error when file doesn't exist. Why? How to distinct real execution error from file absence?

*Update*:

From man page:
The **test** utility evaluates the expression and, if it evaluates to true, returns a zero (true) exit status; otherwise it returns 1 (false).  If there is no expression, test also returns 1 (false).

Does it mean that error - correct behavior? is it possible to check file and then execute `npm install` using bash only?

Comment: What happens when you run it directly in bash?

Comment: Nothing, no errors, if file not exist. `npm install` will not execute.

Comment: Try using absolute path. ``file doesn't exist`` error means that the file does not exist. Most probably you're working in another directory. So, yeah, try testing an absolute path. Also ``-e`` flag is probably not what you're looking for.. You're looking for ``-f``

Comment: I've tried with absolute path before - same result. With `-f` flag too.. it means only that file is regular. I could use it, but effect - same. Error object is `{"killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute

```
test -e package.json && npm install
```

and `package.json` doesn't exist, then `test` will fail, `npm` will not execute (because of `&&`) and the entire expression will be considered to have failed. (That shouldn't be surprising; if it were not the case, you couldn't do things like `a && b && c` or `a && b || c`.)

So if you want the entire expression to return success, you need to indicate that:

```
test -e package.json && npm install || true
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that it's expected behavior and how to overcome this :)